# Obtaining a Bool out of [Maybe Bool] which is guaranteed to contain at least one Just

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, option-type, monadplus

I have an input `list`  of type `[Maybe SomeType]` and a predicate `p` of type `SomeType -> Bool`, and I want to answer the question *"Does the predicate `p` hold for all `SomeType`s that happen to be in the input?"*.

The first part is easy: `(map . fmap) p list` is of type `[Maybe Bool]`.

One important info is that I know that `length list >= 1` and `all isNothing list == False` both hold, so there must be at least a `Just True` in `(map . fmap) p list`.

But how do I pull out one single `Bool` out of that list?

I thought that I could take advantage of folding (e.g. via `foldl`) and `Maybe`'s `MonadPlus` instance, doing something like the following:

```hs
allTrueOrNothing :: [Maybe Bool] -> Bool
allTrueOrNothing = fromJust . foldl mplus mzero
```

but this is not quite true, because `mplus` returns the left operand if it's `Just something` regardless of what `something` is, so `allTrueOrNothing` will return `True` even if its input is `[Just True, Just False]`.

What's the cleanest/most idiomatic way I can accomplish the task?

I see that I could simply `filter` out the `Nothing`s and then `and` together the `Just`s, something like this:

```hs
allTrueOrNothing' :: [Maybe Bool] -> Bool
allTrueOrNothing' = all fromJust . filter (fmap not isNothing)
```

But I was more curious to know if there's a way to have those `Maybe Bool`s behave like a `Monoid` aware of its `Bool` content.

Comment: Can you get ride of the `Nothing` values *before* you map `p`? `all p . catMaybes`. Since `all p [] == True`, it doesn't matter if there's at least one non-`Nothing` value in the original input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way is `and . catMaybes`.

But you wanted to use Monoid that is aware of its `Bool` content, in the `&&` kind of way. That's `All`:

```
> foldMap (fmap All) [Just True,Nothing,Just False]
Just (All {getAll = False})

> foldMap (fmap All) [Just True,Nothing,Just True]
Just (All {getAll = True})
```

Comment: Accepting this as it addresses the question more closely, imho, despite the answer leveraging the `Foldable` instance of `Maybe` is great too.

Comment: @Enlico you meant "besides" perhaps, instead of "despite"? but anyway it doesn't. it uses `instance Monoid a => Monoid (Maybe a)` and `instance Foldable []`: `foo :: (a -> Maybe All) -> [a] -> Maybe All ; foo = foldMap` works as well. (cf. `foldMap :: (Monoid m, Foldable t) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m`). :)

Comment: No, I meant _despite_. The problem is that I mistakenly wrote _the_ instead of _another_ right before _answer_. I was referring to Daniel Wagner's answer.

Answer (score 11):

I would just use `all` directly:

```
all . all :: (a -> Bool) -> [Maybe a] -> Bool
```

If you must have the phase distinction you describe for some reason, then you can use the specialization `and = all id`:

```
all and :: [Maybe Bool] -> Bool
```

Comment: It took me a second to realize that this works becuse `[Maybe a]` is of the form `f (g a)` where `f` and `g` are both foldables. Clever (perhaps a bit too much ;-), but I like it).

Comment: It helps to be explicit about type argument `all @[] . all @Maybe` and `all @[] $ and @Maybe`

Comment: Do `Foldable`s compose in general?

Comment: @chepner Yes, via `foldMap = foldMap . foldMap`.

Comment: @DanielWagner It typechecks, sure, but I wasn't sure if there was some law that could be violated depending on the monoid.

Comment: @chepner The `Foldable` laws aren't very interesting: if you define only `foldMap`, all of the laws are satisfied by the default implementations of the other methods, because the laws only relate `Foldable` methods to each other.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work:

```
> and . catMaybes $ [Just False, Nothing, Just False]
False
> and . catMaybes $ [Just False, Nothing, Just True]
False
> and . catMaybes $ [Just True, Nothing, Just True]
True
```

You can use `catMaybes` to convert the list to `[Bool]`, and `and` to conclude.

(Note that this will return `True` on an all-`Nothing`s list, which is an "impossible" case according to your assumptions.)

If you absolutely want to use a monoid, I guess you can do that, but it's a bit cumbersome. It would involve to wrap each element of the list in some `newtype And = And (Maybe Bool)`, then defining the relevant monoid instance, then  `mconcat`ing everying, and finally unwrapping.

Untested code:

```
newtype And = And (Maybe Bool)

instance Semigroup And where
   And Nothing  <> x            = x
   x            <> And Nothing  = x
   And (Just a) <> And (Just b) = And (Just (a && b))

instance Monoid And where
   mempty = Nothing

allTrueOrNothing :: [Maybe Bool] -> Bool
allTrueOrNothing = fromMaybe False . coerce . mconcat @And . coerce
```

Comment: `newtype And = And (Maybe Bool)`?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I edited with the related instances. Hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: `newtype And = And (Maybe Bool) deriving (Semigroup, Monoid) via Maybe All`